# Linkify in textview which is placed in the listview

Tags: android, linkify

I have a listview where every single element of the list has a textview. This textview has following properties:

chatText.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
Linkify.addLinks(chatText, Linkify.ALL);

now all links are appearing properly but when i click on them the app is force stopping and displaying following errors:

android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?

how to solve this error??

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using incorrect context, use the context of your activity.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this flag

> `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` before calling your startActivity()

to your intent.

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

Comment: When you Linkify text, it does not expose the intent. You need to provide a method to do that before attempting to modify it.